# How long time does it take an infinite number of monkeys to type the collected works of Shakespeare?

Tags: mathematics, literature

Imagine an infinite number of monkeys typing random texts on typewriters. 
Each monkey has same single unit of typewriter. 
We assume that typewriters and monkeys are ideal i.e. do not need to be fed/repaired etc.
On infinite time, an infinite number of monkeys will reveal a monkey which managed to type the collected works of Shakespeare.

According to https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/stats/, the collected works of Shakespeare contain 884,421 words.

> **Question**: What is the expected time span for this experiment where the probability of the target event goes close to 1?

Comment: Isn't the time span infinite? You explicitly say "On infinite time"

Comment: If there is a *truly infinite* number of monkeys, then at least one of them is going to type the complete works of Shakespeare right off the bat.

Comment: @F1Krazy. This is kind of my answer. I think the one after the last monkey will do that. But not sure.

Comment: Not sure but what do you mean by repairing monkeys ? And it just takes the time for one to type any text of the same length as the collected works

Comment: An infinite number of monkeys would type every known work of literature known to mankind (and also pre-write every work to come). Go monkeys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It depends on the typing speed of the monkeys. Let's say the speed is the same for all of them and it's X chars/second.
>  Let's say that ShakesBEER wrote N characters in his work then it will take  $\frac{N}{X}$ seconds. Since we have infinite monkeys and the probability of one of them typing randomly to get the full works is a bit over 0, there is for sure one (actually an infinite number of them) that will start typing immediately the right words.
>  And this will happen with a probability of 1.